# Gmail delay receiving email from our domain

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, spf, dkim, dmarc

I am getting this message when sending Email to Gmail.

> this message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 421-4.7.0 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 421-4.7.0 message has been blocked.

I have try adding `SPF`,`DMARC` and `DKIM` but still getting the same error message.

Comment: have you registered your domain with postmaster.google.com?

Comment: yes still the same problem

Comment: What email sending service are you using and what is the domain.